# static folder doesn't work in other route

Tags: node.js, static, ejs

My static in app.js looks:
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

I want to show some pics, but these don't work in other routes than `/`.

My pics:
`<img src="<%=value.pic_1%>"/>` - it works if action is in `/index` but if my action is in `/cars` it doesn't work! I read all questions from stack and noone helped me :/